# Сравнение списков ArrayList

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String[]> family1=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String[]> family2=new ArrayList<>();
    String[]name1=new String[]{"Иванов","Иван","Иванович"};
    String[]name2=new String[]{"Петров","Петр","Петрович"};
    String[]name3=new String[]{"Шварцнейгер","Адольф"};

    String[]name4=new String[]{"Иванов","Иван","Иванович"};
    String[]name5=new String[]{"Петров","Петр","Петрович"};
    String[]name6=new String[]{"Шварцнейгер","Адольф"};

    family1.add(name1);
    family1.add(name2);
    family1.add(name3);

    family2.add(name4);
    family2.add(name5);
    family2.add(name6);

    System.out.println(family1.equals(family2));
}
```

Подскажите, как можно сравнить подобные списки, чтобы получить истину?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155283/simple-way-to-compare-2-arraylists

Comment: `Arrays.deepEquals(family1.toArray(), family2.toArray())`

Comment: В данном случае лучше определить класс `PersonName(String family, String name, String patronymic)`, и в нем переопределить функции `equals` и `hashCode`